# How to fix Google App Engine location value?

Tags: google-app-engine, netbeans, location

I moved my projects from old PC to new PC, on the new PC I downloaded the latest Google App Engine 1.3.5 and the directory is "C:\appengine-java-sdk-1.3.5", yet when I build my projects, NetBeans kept saying :

```
C:\Dir_PayPal_Monitor\build.xml:12: The following error occurred while executing this line:
C:\Dir_PayPal_Monitor\nbproject\build-impl.xml:21: The following error occurred while executing this line:
C:\Dir_PayPal_Monitor\nbproject\ant-deploy.xml:10: Cannot find C:\appengine-java-sdk-1.3.4/config/user/ant-macros.xml imported from C:\Dir_PayPal_Monitor\nbproject\ant-deploy.xml
```

For several times, I've opened the "ant-macros.xml" file and changed the value from "appengine-java-sdk-1.3.4" to appengine-java-sdk-1.3.5", it keeps coming back, I wonder where this value "1.3.4" is stored in NB, when it generates the "ant-macros.xml" file, it uses this value, if I can change it to 1.3.5 it will solve the problem, does anyone know where it is ?

Frank

Answer (score 0):

In build.xml, there is a variable called `sdk.dir`. Make sure that points to the correct location.

Comment: I looked at my build.xml, there is no "sdk.dir".

Comment: that may be your problem... find the default build.xml that comes with the sdk and go from there.